# Question about JSONKit analyze

Tags: iphone, ios

First look at my json file, like this:

```
[
  {
    id: 1
    arr: {
        name: "功夫"
        sex: "m"
        age: 40
    }
    GP: [
        {
            Peter: 32
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I used JSONKit analyze this file. and like this code

```
JSONDecoder *jsonDec = [[[JSONDecoder alloc] initWithParseOptions:JKParseOptionNone] autorelease];

dic = [jsonDec objectWithData:data];
if (dic == nil) {
    NSLog(@"dic is nil !!!!!!!!!");
    return;
}

NSLog(@"%d..",[dic count]);
NSLog(@"%@",dic);

if (dic != nil) {
    for (id ary in dic) {
        NSLog(@"kkkkkk %@",[ary objectForKey:@"arr"]);
    }

    for (id key in dic)
    {

        NSLog(@"key: %@ ,value: %@",key,[dic objectForKey:key]);
                    //this line error.
    } 
}
```

when the runtime, it crash.

```
2011-07-28 19:24:27.499 MyJSONTest[27274:207] -[JKArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x692ee40
2011-07-28 19:24:27.500 MyJSONTest[27274:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JKArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x692ee40'
```

I need some help, thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the code you are running has no idea that **JKArray** has a **objectForKey:** function.

But are you sure that JKArray has a **objectForKey:** ? are you not thinking about **JKDictionary**?

NSDirectory runs with keys, and NSArrays have **objectatindex:**

Check the head of your file. Have you included the right file ? adding the @class header is **not** enough if you want to use NSObject functionality.

Comment: thanks Munch. I think you're right, but how can I do to solve this problem I already add @class JSONDecoder; in the .h file and also add #import "JSONKit.h" in the .m file. thank you!

Comment: Just realised we are talking arrays, not dictionaries. Try using objectAtIndex instead, or look at my post (edited it)

Comment: But are you sure that JKArray has a **objectForKey:** ? are you not thinking about **JKDictionary**?    yes! it's a **JKDictionary**,how can I do to next step? thanks very much!